# Parse Week, Hour & minute

Tags: java, java-time, dayofweek, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to load from XML a schedule field which looks like this: "MON 17:20"

I want to avoid parse manually using string replace e.t.c. I checked online for this code

```
final String dateInString = "Mon, 05 May 1980";
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
final LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(dateInString, formatter);
```

But it has no week field (I cannot retrieve the week). Is there any similar short parse system?

Comment: what should be year and month ?

Comment: What date should `MON 17:20` be parsed into? Which Monday?

Comment: My code basically schedule every X day of Week in that specific time. So my xml field goes like <holder schedule="MON 18:30, TUE 18:30"> and repeat this every week. I don't need to parse month or year. So basically i do a split "," and parse all dates in that schedule to schedule which is the next available.

Comment: @KbantikiMixaniki - Without year and month, it's **impossible** to calculate which week this `Mon` or `Tue` belong to. Do you mean starting from the current date?

Comment: @KbantikiMixaniki [Have you read this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61533888/507738) What exactly do you want to do with the day-of-week and time? Do you want to combine it with a year and month, or perhaps a year and week number?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
final String dateInString = "Thu Apr 30, 2020 17:20";
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
final LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

The above parses to this.

```
2020-04-30T17:20
```

If you want the week you can do this.

```
System.out.println(dateTime.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(dateTime.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Prints

```
5
18
```

Updated Answer.

```
final String dateInString ="MON 17:20";
String[] vals = dateInString.split("\\s+");
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
final LocalTime dateTime = LocalTime.parse(vals[1], formatter);
System.out.println(vals[0] + " " + dateTime);
```

Prints

```
MON 17:20
```

Read the details at [ChronoField](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) 
Check the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package for more on the Java Temporal capabilities.

Comment: Hello sir. Thank you for respond. I tried the following:  final String dateInString = "Thu 17:20";
  final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE HH:mm"); but it give error. I only need parse Day of Week and time but seems i can't right?

Comment: So i don't have other option other than do it manually with splits and replace right?

Comment: This is my code so far base on your example: https://pastebin.com/LySpaAQe
You find it ok? Also i need make a static method to convert short week to int so i can add it in Calendar or there is also short way using libraries? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible with the Java 8 Date & Time API.

You seem to have three fields: the day-of-week, the hour-of-day and the minute-of-hour. This could normally be parsed using `DateTimeFormatter::ofPattern` with the formatting string `EEE HH:mm`, but the problem is that `MON` (in all caps) is not standard; it should be `Mon` instead.

So we need to build our formatter using the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, instructing that the string should be parsed in a case-insensitive manner:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendPattern("EEE HH:mm")
    .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

The only thing to do is parsing the fields using

```
TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parse(elem);
```

Now `parsed` contains the abovementioned parsed fields.

#### To a datetime

Of course, you don't *have* to convert this to an actual date. There are many use cases where one don't want a date, but rather only a day-of-week and the time. [This is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61440567/is-there-a-class-for-encoding-a-local-time-of-week-in-java).

But if you, for example, want to get the current date and adjust it to match the data from your schedule, you can do something like this:

```
TemporalAdjuster adj = TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.of(parsed.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK)));
LocalDateTime now = LocalDate.now()
    .atTime(LocalTime.from(parsed))
    .with(adj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your LocalDate object into the example shown here:
[Get Week Number of LocalDate (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012434/get-week-number-of-localdate-java-8)

That should get it for you.

From the link above pass your 'dateTime' field in the code like...

```
    TemporalField woy = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).weekOfWeekBasedYear(); 
int weekNumber = dateTime.get(woy);
```

Depending on your locale and where this code will run you might want to consider WeekFields.ISO as mentioned at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn’t that it’s difficult to parse using a `DateTimeFormatter`. The problem is that we haven’t got a good type to parse into. The information doesn’t fit in a `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`, for example. And depending on what you need for your scheduler I think that the solution is to parse into two objects instead of one: a day of week and a time of day.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("EEE H:mm")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    String scheduleString = "MON 17:20";

    TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parse(scheduleString);
    DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(parsed);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(parsed);

    System.out.format("Schedule: every %s at %s", dow, time);
```

Output:

> Schedule: every MONDAY at 17:20

Explicit use of the `TemporalAccessor` interface is considered low-level, but I much prefer this solution over `String.replace()` or `String.split()`. If you want to avoid the low-level interface, just parse the string twice, once into a `DayOfWeek` and once into a `LocalTime`.